# Create several DIV containers using for loop in PHP

Tags: php

Just wanted to ask how can I (if it is possible at all) create several DIV containers using for loop in PHP. Thank You.

Comment: Yes.  It's possible to write a loop in PHP.  And it's possible to output HTML to the page in PHP.  Have you, well, *tried*?

Comment: Yeah so originally I was trying to use to loop but I guess I was dumb enough to not realize that I can echo div tags.

Comment: To get assistance with code problems, you should always try to post the minimal complete verifiable amount of code to reproduce your problem, *or* the code you have tried so far. For assistance with this, you can read the article [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the Help Center (otherwise you get heavily down-voted, like what has happened here).

Comment: Noted thanks. First time posting here so did not know it would work, but yeah I should have posted something for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo '<div>$i</div>';
}
```

```php
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) { ?>
    <div><?= $i; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

```php
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++): ?>
    <div><?= $i; ?></div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

If we're really going down this silly road...

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach(array_fill(0, 999, 'why!?') as $key => $really) {
    echo "<li>$key: $really</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: That helps a lot thank you. I was trying to use the loops to do exactly that but had a brain fart and thought echo would not work with it.